# Cannot find module in ruby on rails app using react-rails

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpacker, react-rails

I have a rails app where I’m trying to add packages a simple react-rails component to a view I have.
I’m able to get the react component to load fine in my .erb view without the packages.
The react component is in /app/javascript/components. However, when importing modules into my component HelloWorld.jsx, the app crashes and says it can’t find the module.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'connectkit'
    at webpackMissingModule (application.js:1:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (application.js:1:1)
    at ./app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:62:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at bootstrap:83:1
    at bootstrap:83:1
```

I’ve installed the modules with yarn add <module_name>, and I see the package in my package.json and in my node_modules. Tried removing my node_modules folder and reinstalling, but that didn’t solve the problem. What is the correct way to add a package to a ruby on rails app with react-rails?
The module works fine if the imports are commented out and shows in my app but as soon as I include the imports, I get the error above

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { WagmiConfig, createClient } from 'wagmi';  // importing these breaks the component;
import { ConnectKitProvider, ConnectKitButton, getDefaultClient } from 'connectkit'; // importing these breaks the component, works fine without;

const alchemyId = process.env.ALCHEMY_ID;

const client = createClient(
  getDefaultClient({
    appName: 'Your App Name',
    alchemyId,
  })
);

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <WagmiConfig client={client}>
          <ConnectKitProvider>
            Greeting: {this.props.greeting}
            <ConnectKitButton />
          </ConnectKitProvider>
        </WagmiConfig>
        Greeting: {this.props.greeting}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

HelloWorld.propTypes = {
  greeting: PropTypes.string,
};
export default HelloWorld;
```